# Yii - CJuiAutoComplete

Tags: php, yii, autocomplete

i have 2 CJuiAutoComplete fields in my View, Project Name which has the value `$search` and Employee Name which has the value `$search_employee`.

My first field works fine..
In my second field, when i type something, suggestions show. But when i try to hover or select an item, the suggested dropdown disappears. How is this happening.? i just copied this field with my first one.

this is my code.

```
<div class="form-group"> <label>Project Name</label>
    <div class="controls" style='margin-top: 5px;'>
        <?php
            $form->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array('name' => 'search',
                'source' => Evaluation::searchEvaluation(),
                'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Search'),
                'options' => array(
                ),
                'value' => $search,
            ));
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

second field

```
<div class="form-group"> <label>Employee Name</label>
    <div class="controls" style='margin-top: 5px;'>
        <?php
            $form->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array('name' => 'search_employee',
                'source' => Evaluation::searchEvaluation(),
                'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Search Employee'),
                'options' => array(
                ),
                'value' => $search_employee,
            ));
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try putting different `id` parameter for both widget

Comment: @litlitDM works fine for me, there must be some other problem, check browsers console, `'value' => $search_employee,` or `'source' => Evaluation::searchEvaluation(),`

Comment: thanks @Criesto i commented out the 'source' and it is ok now.